# Imprimir em formato A3 e A4

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou precisando desenvolver algo que consiga imprimir em formatos A3 e A4, exatamente igual ao desse site:

http://mapas.fortaleza.ce.gov.br

Notem que ao clicar no ícone de impressão primeiro ele redimensiona no formato correto e depois ao clicar em Imprimir, ele mostra o preview exatamente como ele quer na impressão, somente com o mapa, centralizado e no formato requerido.

Sendo bem sincero, eu não tenho nem base de como fazer isso, pois eu nunca fiz. Estou usando Javascript com o Leaflet, como que devo proceder? Ainda não tenho linguagem de backend, mas ainda estão decidindo entre desenvolver usando Java ou Python, infelizmente essa decisão não é minha. Gostaria que me dessem apenas um norte do que fazer e como fazer e se possível algum exemplo, algum plugin ou framework que eu possa usá-lo para tal.

Obrigado!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a regra CSS @media print e começar ocultando os menus e outras coisas que você não queira imprimir

```
@media print {    
.no-print, .no-print * {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Aí quando você abrir a tela de impressão no javascript

```
window.print();
```

Tudo que possuir a classe no-print não será mostrado na tela de impressão do navegador, você também pode customizar o tamanho do que você deseja imprimir dentro do CSS @media print {}, na tela padrão de impressão é possível mudar o layout e tamanho do papel, então você pode ir testando e ajustando o que você deseja mostrar.
Espere ter ajudado

Comment: Excelente ideia! Não havia pensado nisso, eu lembro que já usei esse @media print do css uma vez, mas estava tão focado em algum plugin/framework que nem passou pela minha cabeça testar algo mais simples. Obrigado!